# Many to many relations and history tables

Tags: database, database-design, model, many-to-many, relational-database

Suppose I have `Item` and `Tag`, each of which have an `id` and `name` column only, and an `Item_Tag_Map` table that has a composite `Item.id, Tag.id` primary key.

If I want to implement a history table for `Item` and `Tag`, this seems relatively straightforward - I can add a third column `revision` and a trigger to copy into an `ItemHistory` or `TagHistory` table with `id, revision` as primary key and `operation` ("INSERT","UPDATE",etc). Since I may want to "delete" items, I can go about this one of two ways:

- Add another column on `Item` or `Tag` for `is_active`, and do not actually delete any rows ever
- Delete rows, but record the deletion in the history table as a `delete` operation, and on an `Item` or `Tag` insert, make sure to get the latest `revision` number from the `ItemHistory` or `TagHistory` table with that item, and set it to be that

The second option leaves a bad taste in my mouth, so I am fine with using the first. After all, why should I really ever *need* to delete an item when I can just modify it or change its active status?

Now, I've run into the same problem for the history table on the `Item_Tag_Map` table, but this time, neither option seems all that attractive. If I choose to add an `is_active` for the `Item_Tag_Map`, the logic of finding out whether a tag is mapped to an item changes from:

> Get ALL tag_mapping for THESE items

to

> Get ALL tag_mapping for THESE items WHERE is_active

The implicit idea that the presence of a mapping means that the mapping exists goes away. The set of unmapped item-tags not only includes all the ones that are not present in the table, but also the ones where `is_active` is false.

On the other hand, if I choose the second option, it's still rather ugly.

I'm sure people have run into this problem many times before, and I am interested in learning how you have dealt with it.

Answer (score 2):

My answer depends on a few things, so I'll try to state my assumptions.

No matter what I think is_active on Item and Tag are ok. If the record size grows very fast on those two entities, then consider running a nightly job to move the inactive records to an archived version of the tables. This can be used for reporting or auditing of things later. You can also write a script to restore records if you need, but the idea is that your real time tables are fast and without deleted data.

If you allow the user to add/update/delete mappings, then I would consider the table the same as Item and Tag. Add the flag and use it in your queries. It doesn't seem ugly to me - I've seen it before.

If the mapping table isn't under user control, then I would guess you would use the is_active flag on either Item or Tag to determine whether or not a query could be run.

Just know that once you add that flag, people will forget to use it. I know I've done it many times, ("Why did I get so many records, what am I missing? Oh yeah, is_active...)